# Android add date by array

Tags: android, arrays, date, calendar

I have an array populated with the "ID" of a database table.
At position 0, I want to set the calendar with the date of today. at position 1, I want to set the date (day + 1), at position 3, I want to set the date (day + 2) and so on. How can I do?

```
        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int size = id_op.length;//array
        for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){
            //startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            //startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, i);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a day in calender you can use `add` method.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // tomorrow

for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    add c.add(Calendar.DATE, i); to your ith item in database
}
```